# SwiftUI - Check If Image Exist

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, ios13

I am attempting to execute code if an image exist.
The issue is I am unable to capture the state of empty image call.
The result is I get an empty image, but would rather put a placeholder image if possible.

```
   func procImage(inName: String) {


        switch (inName) {

        case inName:
            imageName = inName.lowercased()

        default:
            imageName = "blank"
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please post code that uses this logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This check is easy but you need to be sure that default image always exists.

```
func getSafeImage(named: String) -> Image {
   let uiImage =  (UIImage(named: named) ?? UIImage(named: "Default.png"))!
   return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
}
```

Comment: Although it is okay to use `UIImage` to make a safe `Image`, be warned that it will not scale correctly if it is a vector image. For that to work correctly, `Image` needs to access the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

All the code examples provided as solutions here work, but at the price of a potentially blurry image when you deal with SVGs, which is a big downside to me. Here is a solution preserving vectorial properties of your asset:

```
func getImageNamed(_ imageName: String, fallbackImageName: String) -> Image {
    if UIImage(named: imageName) == nil {
        return Image(fallbackImageName)
    }
    return Image(imageName)                   
}
```

Comment: Came here to give this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func procImage(inName: String) -> UIImage {
    if let confirmedImage = UIImage(named: inName) {
        return confirmedImage
    } else {
        return UIImage(named: "Default_Image.png")!
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not compile, because you need to force the default image to be not nil. return UIImage(named: "Default_Image.png")!

Comment: You are welcome, for other hand the question is about SwiftUI so the method should  return an object of kind Image not a UIImage. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for contributing.
The solutions on offer did not quite work in my case except for Moreno's solution, but offered a path to my solution.
I did not need to store the result of the check, but just validate the existence of the file.
So this is what I came up with which worked.
This may not be the optimal solution, so improved code will be welcomed.

```
func procImage(inName: String) {



        let imageConvertToLowercase = inName.lowercased()

        if getMember.firstName.lowercased() == imageConvertToLowercase {

            if (UIImage(named: imageConvertToLowercase) != nil) {

            imageName = imageConvertToLowercase

        } else {

            imageName = "blank"
        }

        }
    }
```